# jquery added class inside a droppable not becoming resizable if outside drop event

Tags: jquery, draggable, addclass, droppable, resizable

When dropping something in this drop area, the object will be cloned and will get part class.

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    accept: '.drag, .part',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var posizione = ui.position;

        if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('drag') ) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
            $('#board .drag').addClass("part");
            $('.part').removeClass("drag");
        };
       ....
)};
```

There is a way to give doppable/draggable/resizable properties to "part" class without doing this inside drop event, but defining it outside? Because the only way to make it work is to give that inside drop function.

WORK

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    accept: '.drag, .part',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var posizione = ui.position;

        if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('drag') ) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
            $('#board .drag').addClass("part");
            $('.part').removeClass("drag");
        };

        $('.part').resizable({
            containment: "#board",
            aspectRatio: true
        });
        ....
)};
```

NOT WORK

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    accept: '.drag, .part',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var posizione = ui.position;

        if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('drag') ) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
            $('#board .drag').addClass("part");
            $('.part').removeClass("drag");
        };

        ....
)};
$('.part').resizable({
            containment: "#workarea",
            aspectRatio: true
});
```

I'm new to javascript and jquery, so if you find other errors, please report.
Thanks for helping.

EDIT: complete code http://jsfiddle.net/funnydj/qtBfJ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By addressing the jQuery collection `$('.part')` inside the `drop` handler, you will affect *all* elements in the document with `class="part"`.

Typically, it is necessary only to address the element that's just been dropped/cloned, and given that that element is given `class="part"`, I'm guessing that only it needs to be addressed. All previously dropped/cloned elements should already have received the appropriate treatment.

If I'm right, then you probably want something like this :

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    accept: '.drag, .part',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var posizione = ui.position;

        if(ui.helper.hasClass('drag') ) {
            var $part = ui.helper.clone().removeClass("drag ui-draggable-dragging").addClass("part");
            $part.appendTo($(this));
            $part.resizable({
                containment: "#board",
                aspectRatio: true
            });
            $part.draggable({
                tolerance: 'fit',
                revert: 'invalid', //resterà non valido finchè non droppo in un punto valido
                containment: "#workarea",
                stop: function () {
                    var top2 = ui.position.top;
                    var left2 = ui.position.left;
                    $("#workarea").append('<div>spostata</div>');
                    $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid'); //quando lo lascio torna indietro perche' il revert è invalid'
                }
            });
            $part.droppable({
                greedy: true,
                //tolerance: 'intersect',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!$(ui.helper).hasClass('part')) {
                        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        inserite++;
        $("#workarea").append('<div>' + top + '-' + left + '--' + inserite + '</div>');
    }
});
```

You could tidy things significantly by defining the option-maps in an outer scope, but they must be applied inside.

I would probably do something like this :

```
var inserite = 0;

part_options = {
    resizable: function(ui) {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    draggable: function(ui) {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    droppable: function(ui) {
        return {
            ...
        }
    }
};


$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    accept: '.drag, .part',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var posizione = ui.position;

        if(ui.helper.hasClass('drag') ) {
            var $part = ui.helper.clone().removeClass("drag ui-draggable-dragging").addClass("part");
            $part.appendTo($(this));
            $part.resizable(part_options.resizable.call(this, ui));
            $part.draggable(part_options.draggable.call(this, ui));
            $part.droppable(part_options.droppable.call(this, ui));
            //or one long chained command if you prefer.
        };
        inserite++;
        $("#workarea").append('<div>' + top + '-' + left + '--' + inserite + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: All previously dropped/cloned elements must remain draggable, droppable and resizable. Is that the reason i was addressing all the collection (i want to create a sort of image desk). If i give class "part" to last dropped/cloned and outside i address the collection $('.part') giving droppable/draggable/resizable it not works (i'm loosing something here... if you can, help me with that).
Also jquery not remove ui-draggable-dragging after dropping a part, so i've to remove every time, not only when the div is a drag. Anyway the option-map is great hint!!!! thank you!

Comment: `$('.part').resizable(...)` will address only those `.part` elements that exist at the time the statement executes. In your non-working code, no `.part` elements exist at that time; parts, are created later, in response to a drag/drop action. In my code, droppped parts will remain draggable etc. without needing to re-address the whole `.part()` collection. As far as I can tell, only the newly created part needs to be addressed, immediately after it is created. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtBfJ/4/).

Comment: Great! now everything is clear! I will go on with my work and, if i will have more trouble, i hope you will help me again. Thanks!!!